# Rendering CoreText within an irregular shape

Tags: algorithm, text, geometry, word-wrap, core-text

I'm looking for guidance on implementing a view that renders an `NSAttributedString` within a polygon with holes, wrapping and reflowing text to fit the geometry. It's not `CoreText` that's the issue, but the general problem of partitioning an irregular shape into an ordered sequence of squat rectangles.

Similar questions haven't been answered fully:

- How to fill a shape with text in Javascript

  [https://stackoverflow.com/q/3048305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048305/algorithm-for-text-wrapping-within-a-shape)
- CoreText's `CTFramesetter` does not support rendering into a `CGPath`

  [https://stackoverflow.com/q/3813318](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813318/core-text-render-to-an-odd-shape/4049472#4049472)

CoreText handles an unbelievable amount of the grunt work associated with text layout and display, so I can't help but suspect that I'm reinventing a wheel. For the purposes of this question, please assume that I can check the substring that fits within a given rectangle, taking into account word wrap and hyphenation.

**Edit:** I've since decided to just sweep left-to-right drawing as much as fits between boundaries. It looks a bit haphazard even though I'm breaking at natural word boundaries, so I'd still appreciate guidance on how other applications wrap text.

**Edit #2:** It looks decent now that it supports basic word wrap and avoids rendering very short lines. My question must have been too vague. Thanks for looking.

**Edit #3:** Amorya points out that [`CTFramesetter` now accepts any `CGPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005105).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about achieving text wrap with Core Text:

http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/11098565269/text-wrap-with-core-text

The feature is new in iOS 4.3 and MacOS X Lion. You can now firstly draw inside non-rectangular paths, and secondly pass in other paths to mask the flow (i.e. be the holes you wrap around).

Comment: Glad to see it now accepts an arbitrary `CGPath`. That's a proper solution. Thanks for revisiting the question after so long.

Comment: No worries. I was searching for something myself, and couldn't find any questions about it apart from old ones. I don't think they publicised the change very well.