# How to draw a non-rectangle UILabel with paragraph truncation at the end?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uilabel, uitextview

I need to show a body of text similar to the one shown below and limited to the red non-rectangular area. Rob's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270997/how-to-draw-a-non-rectangle-uitextview/9272955?noredirect=1#comment26285449_9272955) question pretty much answers my question as well, but I also need to truncate at tail of the paragraph when the text is too long.

Extra question: is it also possible to set minimum font size similar to UILabel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NSString::sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize` method which is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). You can specify the fontsize and maximum size for the text.

You can also calculate the minimum font size using `NSString::sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` method.

Comment: Ankit, upto my knowledge this works on a standard rectangular area, I need to layout the text on a non-rectangular area as highlighted by the red background above.

Comment: I can think of manipulating your code to divide the area into one or more standard rectangular areas and perform the calculations.

Comment: Reading following post might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158012/rendering-coretext-within-an-irregular-shape